# HTTP Origin header (https://example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://example.com) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma, nginx-config

I am running Nginx server with the puma on https. I configured Letsencrypt for SSL verification. The problem is that the server is running fine but when I try to create a user through devise it throws this error

"HTTP Origin header (https://example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://example.com)"

I tried to modify the nginx.conf configuration as specified over here 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22965#issuecomment-172929004

but still, no luck here is my configuration file

```
upstream puma {

  server unix:///home/ubuntu/blue_whale/example/shared/tmp/sockets/gofickle-puma.sock;
}

server
{
    listen 443 ssl default;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    root /home/ubuntu/blue_whale/example/current/public;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/blue_whale/example/current/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/blue_whale/example/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=31536000”;


  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
```

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but I know there are some nginx options that are order dependent: have you tried putting the proxy_pass before the proxy_set_header's?  That's the only obvious difference I see between your config and the one you referenced.

Comment: @chrisHall I dont think, it is order dependent but still I tried and it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same setup as you and mine is working with the below proxy config:

```
  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }
```

I think it might be the X-Forwarded-Proto and SSL that might be causing your issue, it isn't necessary behind the proxy.